# REACT google maps module not found:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Столкнулся с проблемой при реализации `react google maps`,
при запуске проекта ошибка `module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'google-maps-react'`.

Делал `npm uninstall --save google-maps-react`.

Теперь при установке `npm install --save google-maps-react`, выходят ошибки ERR в терминале.
[image: Ошибки при установке npm i --save google-maps-react]

Код файла MapContainer, который я импортирую в главную страницу

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'
};

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={4}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{
         lat: 6.2518401,
         lng: -75.563591
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: '...'
})(MapContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
npm i --force google-maps-react
```